# DB2 Length function

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to run the below line in an DB2 database but I am receiving an error. The substring function appears to be working however I think the issue is with the Length function.

```
LEFT TRIM(SUBSTRING(MCRDFLWP_REASON.abc,SUBSTRING(MCRDFLWP_REASON.abc,':')+1,LENGTH(MCRDFLWP_REASON.abc))) as "REASON"
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Please post ([edit] into your question) the eaxct error.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the parenthesis in `LEFT` and mix some others. Try this:

```
LEFT(
  TRIM(SUBSTRING(
    MCRDFLWP_REASON.abc,
    SUBSTRING(MCRDFLWP_REASON.abc, ':') + 1
  )),
  LENGTH(MCRDFLWP_REASON.abc)
) as "REASON"
```